# How to set background image for tableView in PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquerytableviewcontrolle

This code in `viewDidLoad` works for adding a background image to a `tableView` in a generic `tableViewController`, however using the Parse SDK, it does not add a background image in a `PFQueryTableViewController`.  What am I doing wrong in the PFQTVC?

```
peopleTableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "SFStreetcar"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out simply placing the code inside `viewWillLayoutSubViews` did the trick:

```
 override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        tableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "SFStreetcar"))
    }
```

If that doesn't work though @user2792129 's solution is worth exploring as well.